# Making a sequence of random variables converge to $0$ almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

> Show that for any sequence $(X_n)$ of random variables there exists a sequence of constants $(A_n)$ such that $\frac{X_n}{A_n}$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

###### My attempt

I choose $A_n$ such that $\Pr\left(|X_n|>\frac{A_n}n\right)<\frac1{2^n}$ and I apply Borel-Cantelli lemma.

But **I do not understand how to apply Borel-Cantelli lemma**.

Thank you.

Comment: By Borel-Cantelli, $\mathbb P\{|X_n|\leq A_n/n\text{ for all but finitely many $n$}\}=1$.

Comment: Now can I say that Xn/An converge to 0 ,a.s?

Comment: This implies that, almost surely, $X_n / A_n <n$ for $n$ large enough, so yes, we have $X_n/A_n \to 0$ almost surely.